# Is it possible to base the slow-growing hierarchy on the ordinal defined as “the height of the minimal model of ZFC (assuming it exists)”?

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ denote the ordinal described in section 2.24 of the book “A zoo of ordinals” [David A. Madore]:

> **2.24.** The smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $L_{\alpha} \models {\text{ZFC}}$ (assuming it exists), i.e., the height of the minimal model of ZFC.

I have found Quote 1 ( [source](https://mathoverflow.net/a/194283) ):

> one can philosophically accept the notion of ordinalhood as somehow describing the "well-definedness" of concepts -- that is, an ordering of the integers is said to be an ordinal if any recursive definition (in a particular formal language) of a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ of the form $$f(n) = F(f\upharpoonleft \{m : m < n\})$$ determines a well-defined total function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

The question is: if we assume that $\alpha$ exists and use this ordinal as the base of [Slow-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-growing_hierarchy), can we assume that $g_{\alpha}(n)$ will, in fact, represent a total function that evaluates to a finite natural number for all $n$? If no (or yes), what is the mathematical explanation? And if the answer is “No”, does this contradict Quote 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you're making a mistake re: the slow-growing hierarchy - it's not indexed by ordinals, but rather **families of fundamental sequences of** ordinals (or copies of ordinals, or etc.). This is an unavoidable difference, since there is in general no good way to assign a fundamental sequence (or copy) to every countable ordinal.

- Incidentally, this can be made precise in various ways - for example, it's consistent with ZF (= set theory without the axiom of choice) that there is no function assigning each countable ordinal a fundamental sequence at all, and "lower down" there are [computability-theoretic obstacles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O) to assigning fundamental sequences to each computable ordinal simultaneously. *(And this is really a general point about hierarchies through the countable ordinals, not the slow-growing hierarchy specifically.)*
- The slow- or fast-growing hierarchies we care about are for this reason *not* defined through all the countable ordinals, but rather only up to some fixed countable ordinal leading up to which we've already defined a family of fundamental sequences ([$\epsilon_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)) is a common stopping point). I've certainly never seen such a hierarchy continued even through all the *computable* ordinals, and $\alpha$ is far, far greater than any computable ordinal.

---

Having said that, the answer to your question is **yes**. For any countable ordinal $\mu$ whatsoever, there is an assignment $\mathfrak{S}$ of fundamental sequences to every limit ordinal $\le\mu$ *(this $\mathfrak{S}$ wont' be unique, but such a thing will exist)*. Using any such $\mathfrak{S}$ we can assign a slow-growing function to each ordinal $\le\mu$ [in the usual way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-growing_hierarchy#Definition). But note that the dependence on the specific choice of $\mathfrak{S}$, coupled with the lack of a general way to pick a *specific* $\mathfrak{S}$, means that in general there is no specific function deserving to be called "**the** $\mu$th slow-growing function."

In particular, the special properties of $\alpha$ are completely irrelevant here. Any countable ordinal (including $\alpha$ if it exists) has fundamental-sequence-families,$^*$ and with respect to each such family there will be an $\alpha$th corresponding slow-growing function.

---

$^*$Why is this? Well, perhaps surprisingly in light of the weird ZF fact mentioned above, this has an easy proof! And one which makes use of the notion of a *copy* of an ordinal.

Specifically, suppose $\theta$ is a countable limit ordinal. Since it's countable, there's a well-ordering $R$ of $\omega$ with order-type $\theta$. *(Note that this $R$ isn't unique - and in fact there's no way to "canonically" pick $R$, and this is why this proof doesn't contradict the weird ZF fact mentioned above!)* I'm going to use $R$ to get a fundamental sequence for every limit ordinal $\le \theta$.

Each $n\in\omega$ has, via $R$, a corresponding ordinal $[n]_R<\theta$: namely, the ordinal corresponding to the ordertype of the set $\{m\in\omega: mRn\}$ ordered by (the restriction of) $R$. For example, taking $\theta=\omega+\omega$ and $R$ to be the ordering $$1\prec 3\prec 5\prec 7\prec ...\prec 0\prec 2\prec 4\prec 6\prec ...,$$ we have $[6]_R=\omega+3$. Now for $\eta\le\theta$ a limit:

- We first define a sequence $(n^\eta_i)_{i\in\omega}$ of natural numbers given by $$n^\eta_i=\min\{m\in\omega: [m]_R<\eta, m>n^\eta_j\mbox{ for all $j<i$}\}.$$ Importantly, **the first "$<$" there refers to the usual ordering on the ordinals, while the "$\min$," the "$>$," and the second "$<$" refer to the usual ordering on the naturals**.
- We now use this to define a sequence of ordinals $(\gamma_i^\eta)_{i\in\omega}$ of ordinals $\le\eta$ given by $\gamma^\eta_i=([n^\eta_i]_R)_{i\in\omega}$.

It's now easy to check that for each limit ordinal $\eta\le\theta$ the sequence $(\gamma_i^\eta)_{i\in\omega}$ is a fundamental sequence for $\eta$.

**For example**, taking $R$ as above and $\eta=\theta=\omega+\omega$, we get $$(n_i^\eta)_{i\in\omega}=(1,2,4,6,8,10,...),$$ and this gives the fundamental sequence $$0,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,...$$

(because $[1]_R=0,[2]_R=\omega+1,[4]_R=\omega+2$, ...).

Comment: I think that for an ordinal which is countable in L you could claim there is still a somewhat canonical fundamental sequence. And here $\alpha$ is certainly countable in L.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, but I think it's important for the OP to *first* understand the general obstacles before turning to situations where they're avoidable.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I knew that the definition of $\alpha$ tells nothing about fundamental sequences, which are required for the slow-growing hierarchy, but I thought that this is only a technical problem that should be solved in arbitrary ways (even if there is in general no good way to do it). And this answer confirmed the expectation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I forgot to clarify. Firstly, why isn't the condition $[m]_R>n^\eta_j$ included (ordering on the ordinals)? Secondly, in the described scheme, how is $n^\eta_i$ defined if $i = 0$? In this case, there is no $j < i$. Does this mean that we should find any natural number that corresponds to the zero ordinal, and, if this number is denoted by $N_0$, continue from $N_0 + 1$? But why can't we choose 0 (which corresponds to $\omega$) as the first element of the fundamental sequence? Then the next $m$ will be 2 because it's the minimal number such that $[m]_R>n^\eta_j$, etc.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Note that $[m]_R$ is an ordinal and $n^\eta_j$ is just some number (even if we think of $n^\eta_j$ as a finite ordinal the comparison $[m]_R>n^\eta_j$ will always return true when $[m]_R>\omega$). For your second question, if you go exactly by the def. given in the answer, you wouldn't pick the number corresponding to zero ordinal (or the next one). You will select the smallest number $m$ such that $[m]_R<\eta$ (the second condition in def. of $n^\eta_i$ will be vacuously true when $i=0$). Also answer has very minor typo for sequence $n^\eta_i$. It should be $(0,2,4,6,...)$

Comment: @SSequence: but if the condition $[m]_R>n^\eta_j$ is not included, then why did you skip the number 1 in this fundamental sequence? Both $[1]_R<\eta$ and $1>0$ are true.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yes you are right that $[1]_R<\eta$ . But it is also true that $[0]_R<\eta$. And when we are trying to find $n^\eta_0$, the second condition ($m>n^\eta_j $$\mbox{ for all $j<i$}$) will be vacuously true (one can plug in $i=0$ in that second condition and check). So the number $0$ is the **smallest** one that satisfies both the conditions.

Comment: For example, in this specific case, we will get $n^\eta_0=\min\{0,1,2,3,4,....\}=0$. That's because for any given number $m$ the first condition $[m]_R<\eta$ will always be true (the second condition condition will turn out to be vacuously true anyway).

Comment: @lyricallywicked I believe the second condition has a typo and should be $[m]_R>[n^\eta_j]_R$ $\mbox{ for all $j<i$}$. I hope that clarifies any confusions.

Comment: (I think I am adding way too many comments ... but anyway)...... Also you might find it interesting to show that given the def. of $n^\eta_i$, the sequence of natural numbers $(n^\eta_i)_{i\in\omega}$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @SSequence: —>the second condition has a typo and should be $[m]_R >[n^\eta_j]_R$ for all $j<i$<— but this is exactly what I was asking about. If this condition is not included, then we cannot skip the number $1$ when $0$ is already in the fundamental sequence, because $[1]_R<\eta$ is true, $[2]_R<\eta$ is true, $2 > 1$ is true and $\min\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\} = 1$ is true. But I should clarify one more thing: if $i = 0$, then $n^\eta_j$ does not exist. Can we simply skip any condition that refers to $n^\eta_j$? I do not understand why it's vacuously true if there is no $j < 0$.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Yes, in the def. of $n^\eta_i$, you can basically skip the second condition when $i=0$.