# Could there be an $\omega_1^{CK}$th hyperoperation?

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, ordinals, hyperoperation

If addition is the first hyperoperation, multiplication is the second, and the $(\alpha+1)$th hyperoperation is repeated occurrences of the $\alpha$th one. Is it possible for a limit ordinal (for example $\omega$) to be $\alpha$ and we use an nth term in its fundamental sequence as the $\alpha$. I don’t know if that’s made any sense so here’s an example.

If we take $\cdot^\alpha$ to mean the $\alpha$th hyperoperator, could we evaluate $n\cdot^\omega m$ to $n\cdot^n m$. This wouldn’t be very unusual so I am going to assume so. Now my question is:

> Is there a way to evaluate a $\omega_1^{CK}$th hyperoperator equation into something we could turn into a finite number.

I’m assuming not as the Church-Kleene ordinal has no fundamental sequence that I know of, but there may be something that I haven’t thought of.

Comment: Is there a reason we cannot evaluate $\alpha$th hyperoperations for $\alpha\ge\omega_1^{CK}$? It seems well-defined and we can evaluate some values. I guess the real problem is it could not be *recursive*.

Comment: That’s the reason I decidedly to go for the Chirch-Kleene ordinal, because if you could do it fro the smallest non-recursive ordinal, it follows you could do it for the others. But no, I don’t see any reason against $\alpha$ being a greater ordinal, the problem is their fundamental sequences can’t be anything recursive and that’s makes it tricky.

Comment: I downvoted this question because you can't jump from "What is $\omega+\omega^2$, because if it is not $\omega^2$ I can prove CH" into "How do I define an $\omega_1^{CK}$th hyperoperation" in a six hours window of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There's an interesting situation here: while the question itself isn't a duplicate, [a previous answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2912194/28111) I think resolves it. I don't quite know what to do in this case, so I've written a same-spirit, different-phrasing below, and not marked this question as a duplicate; to avoid "double-dipping" on reputation, I've marked my answer community wiki.*

---

The difficulty here is that limit stages wind up more complicated than they look at first. The weasel words here are

> its fundamental sequence.

The key point is, **there is no unique fundamental sequence for a limit ordinal**! The "$\lambda$th hyperfunction" isn't fully determined by $\lambda$; we *also* have to choose a fundamental sequence for $\lambda$ (and indeed for each limit ordinal $<\lambda$). One might hope that this choice winds up being insignificant, but in fact it's not: different hyperoperations corresponding to the same ordinal can vary wildly.

If you don't require canonicity, then there's no problem - fixing a system of fundamental sequences for all limit ordinals up to a certain point will define a hyperoperation at that point - but the point is that no good "all-the-way-up" (or even a-little-bit-of-the-way-up) theory of hyperoperations exists.

---

So what happens when we actually *do* talk about ordinal-indexed hyperoperations?

When we say something like "the $\omega^\omega$th hyperoperation" - e.g. in the context of [fast-growing hierarchies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) - in the background we're assuming a fixed *notation system* for the ordinals in question, and this amounts to a choice of fundamental sequences. But this notation system can only reach a small ways up (e.g. to $\epsilon_0$ in the case of the Wainer hierarchy); in particular, there is no recursive way to assign a unique fundamental sequence to every recursive limit ordinal.

- This is reflected in the *non-linear* structure of [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O): Kleene provides a system to (essentially) assign fundamental sequences to *recursive presentations of* recursive ordinals, but two different presentations of the same ordinal can get different wildly fundamental sequences.

That said, there is a arguably-reasonable way one can try to go beyond $\omega_1^{CK}$ (indeed, all the way up to $\omega_1^L$, the first $L$-uncountable ordinal) in a canonical way - [mastercodes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183740554). But this gets extremely technical. And it's consistent that $\omega_1^L$ itself is countable, so even this trick won't get us very far.

Comment: There is a paper by the name "An extended arithmetic of ordinal numbers", which seems at least somewhat accessible (even to me). I haven't really read it or even skimmed it though. But the introductory paragraph seems to be of  relevance to idea of hyperoperations. Anyway, I thought I would mention it ...... partly because there seem to a good number of questions under this tag that have at least some link to "hyperoperations", but I haven't this particular paper mentioned (at least for the questions that I have viewed). Maybe I missed it or maybe there is some specific reason for it.

Comment: The dead link to the paper on mastercodes used to go to this paper: Harold T. Hodes, *[Jumping Through the Transfinite: The Master Code Hierarchy of Turing Degrees](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=hodes+jumping+through+transfinite),* The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 45, No. 2 (Jun., 1980), pp. 204-220; [DOI: 10.2307/2273183](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273183), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183)